# How to get Button styles as Android 4.0?

Tags: android, user-interface

In Ice Cream Sandwich phone the buttons are a different style (without border), How can we implement such buttons in our applications?

Comment: FYI, the buttons are not because of ICS, its on the OEM to implement the look and feel of UI. Every manufacturer can have their different kind of buttons.
You need to have images that look identical to those ones. And put it as a background to your button.

Comment: I think this post will be useful to you: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/android-design-v2-now-with-stencils.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get all system drawables and all the resources from [here](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) (android 4 source).